# Optional columns to filter dataBase records

Tags: mysql, playframework, ebean

How should I use the `finder` of Ebean to create a query with optional columns to filter some data?

I want to get a `List<User>` for instance. Imagine I have 3 columns to filter: by Name, by genre and something else. If I select the genre, the query should list all records of genre selected, after that, if I select name John and genre male, the query should List all "John" who are "male" and it's so on.

I know to create simple querys to find for a column:

```
find.where().eq("ex1",var1).eq("ex2", var2).findList();
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [ExpressionList](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/ExpressionList.html). Here is the sample, if the conditions in the `if statement` met, then the expression will be included on the where clause.

```
public static List<User> filterUsers(int user_no, String genre, String name){

    com.avaje.ebean.ExpressionList expressionList = find.where().eq("user_no", user_no);

    if(condition1)
        expressionList.eq("genre", genre);

    if(condition2)
        expressionList.eq("name", name);

    return expressionList.findList();

}
```

Comment: It seems to me a good idea. Just one question. The condition 'else if' could difficult the filter right? If i use 'if's', for instance, if(genre != null) {include on the where clause} ... if(name != null){include on the where clause} . ExpressionList's are used for "manage" the query ? Thank's in advance

Comment: i will try your suggestion and then i give you a feedback. Thanks

Comment: @HugoMachado Sorry, i little bit confused with `else if` part, you may use `else if` or `multiple if's` depends on you requirement. I think it won't make the filter difficult.

Comment: your suggestion runs well. Thanks a lot !